# T-SQL Trigger to watch for secondary condition

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I feel this is a bit obscure, but I am having some trouble with a trigger I am trying to create;

There are two tables to monitor; One for JobLock and one for Orders

First I need to watch for an order record lock to be deleted from JobLock, and then I need to wait for an update to the Orders table before I can execute an update to the Orders of my own. The asynchronisity is a bit awkward, but if my trigger fires on the first criteria, only, the Orders table does not get updated as intended.

Any suggestions how I could get around this?

Comment: My first suggestion would be to elaborate on your question. It is sufficiently vague that it is nearly impossible to answer. Maybe you want a trigger on the Orders table? With no details this is a guessing game. Here is a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I wish I could monitor the Orders table alone, but because the associated application keeps an internal copy of the records, it compares its held values with the values in the table, and if it notices that something has changed, it throws a rejection and fails its own update - with a notice to the user that it noticed something has changed. I will keep fiddling a bit more with your suggestion, as it is the one that makes the most sense to me at the present. Thank you!

Comment: Without a solid definition of what you want to do, there is no way anybody can help you.